# why don't we see the ios app setting page anymore?

Tags: ios, flutter

So I am using flutter-permission-handler to handle all the permission functionality,

for E.G

```
  // Location Permission
  askForLocation() async {
    // Permission type
    var status = await Permission.location.request();

    if (status.isGranted) {
      _location.value = status.isGranted;
      update();
    } else {
      print('open setting');
      openAppSettings();
    }
  }
```

work as expected on android but when it comes to ios it always returns **permanently denied**

however, with that kind of return it should open the app setting page, it opens only the home setting page on the simulator and a physical device.

my first response was to try to get the app from the setting page I couldn't find the app itself.

you can see the behaviour in this video
https://youtu.be/ugpFMFyKhLY

anyone facing the same issue?